# Sorting items by data-title with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having problem with sorting items by data-title attribute. I found couple of solutions over internet that works but when I implement them into my code nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in this code?

jQuery code:

```
var thumbnail = views[0].productThumbnail ? views[0].productThumbnail : views[0].thumbnail,
    productTitle = views[0].productTitle ? views[0].productTitle : views[0].title;

   var $lastItem = $('<div/>', {
                            'class': 'fpd-item fpd-tooltip text-title '+lazyClass,
                            'data-title': productTitle,
                            'data-source': thumbnail,
                            'html': productTitle
                        });

            $lastItem.sort(function(a, b) {
                var nameA = a.attr('data-title').toUpperCase(), // ignore upper and lowercase
                        nameB = b.attr('data-title').toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
                if (nameA < nameB) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (nameA > nameB) {
                    return 1;
                }
                //same
                return 0;
            }).appendTo($gridWrapper);
```

Thank you for your answers.